# SSIS Create table which is destination in flow

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2008

I have a database that is dropped and recreated completely. I want to schedule a SSIS package that:

- executes a SQL script that creates TableA
- than proceeds to the dataflow task that transfers data from source table to TableA.

Problem is that I get an error that says that TableA does not exist as destination. So the validation sees that in my dataflow task the destination does nog exist.

How can I set the routine, such that step 1 gets done before step 2 in one dtsx?

Please note that solutions such as truncation are not an option for me.

Comment: Try setting the property DelayValidation = True for the Data Flow task.

Comment: @JacobH THANKS!! I actually just found a post that states the same thing. http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/09/ssis-what-is-delay-validation-property.html

Comment: Works fine, so simple!

Comment: Great! I will add as an answer so future users can see the solution.

Comment: Probably duplicate [Dynamically create table in SSIS data flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234212/dynamically-create-table-in-ssis-data-flow#7234372)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SSIS package, under the properties for the Data Flow Task, set `Delay Validation` property equal to `True`.

This will delay the validation of the step until run-time, after the table has been created by the previous Execute SQL Task.

Careful that some errors may be suppressed when using this property.